# jQuery .on() syntax and passing multiple arguments to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following script which does not work on Firefox it seems to work on Google chrome.

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_2').on('click', function () {addselectable(event, 7)});

     $(function() {
       $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
        });  
    });

    </script>

     function addselectable (event, size) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert('hello');
        var s = size;
        var p = $('<ol>').attr('id', 'selectable');
        var count = 0
        for (var i = s; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            var li = $('<li>').attr('class', 'ui-state-default').text(count);
             $(li).appendTo(p)
             p.append(li);
        }
        $(p).appendTo('body');
        alert('I am done');

//};
```

}

How can I pass multiple arguments to my function 'addselectable' in the on click event, is there an alternative way of doing it that will work on all browsers?

Comment: you never defined `event`. Some browsers have it defined on `window` by default, other's don't. The others will fail with your current code. The javascript error you are getting should have made that very obvious.

Comment: Define "does not work on Firefox." Tell us what it should do. Don't make us figure out what your code should be doing. Please don't post code with a lot of commented out code. That just confuses us. It might be confusing you as well. Be specific about what isnt' working and HOW it isn't working.

Comment: the jQuery documentation is very helpful for determining what parameters to expect in your callbacks - http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: wat doesn't work....mind explaining a bit

Comment: I figured it out from an answer below, basically the onclick event wasn't calling the function addeslectable in firefox because of the wrong syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

event should goes as argument of function(event)

Change

```
$('#btn_2').on('click', function () {addselectable(event, 7)});
```

To

```
$('#btn_2').on('click', function (event) {addselectable(event, 7)});
```

Try it though it is not tested by me.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the `event` argument to the actual event handler:

```
$('#btn_2').on('click', function (event) {addselectable(event, 7)});
```

What you have works in Chrome because it mimics IE and exposes a global `event` object. Firefox doesn't.